# Unable to publish Windows Store application

Tags: windows, store, xap

Hello I try to publish a WP8 application in my Developer Microsoft Account (https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-FR/dashboard)

Whe I go to my Application / Submission 1 / Package. The web site does not allow me to Upload my XAP File :

[image]

---

I also tried with different Navigator : Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox.

In the console they have this error :[image]

---

Is there a report?

Do you  have the same problem ?

Thank you so much !!

Comment: It would be helpful if you translated the error message into English. (Which would also force you to transcribe it into plain text, so that it is searchable.)

Comment: Hello if you want, but I dont think its my navigator problem :
(1) = Your browser may not support file uploading. Use a browser that can handle HTML5.
(2) : {{deviceFamilyAbandonmentDetectionError}}
(3) : One or more of your XAP packages are redundant and must be removed. Delete unnecessary packages.

Ps : This is the first time I upload package (so I dont have redudant package)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, also in french.
Try replacing "fr-fr" in url by "en-us" : it worked for me, no more error